# I want to print the matrix on the arrow from A to B. How can I write?

Tags: matrices, mapping, transformation

I am working on quiver representation. 
I want to print the matrix on the arrow from A to B. How can I write?
For example:

```
For linear transformation  $k^{3} \arrow{r} k^{2}$
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show what you try so far. is this math expression or an image?

Comment: see if `\[ k^{3} \xrighttarrow{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4 \end{smallmatrix}\right]} k^{2} \]` (`amsmath` package is needed) gives what you looking for.

Answer (score 4):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
For linear transformation  $k^{3} \xrightarrow{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
                                                               1 & 2\\
                                                               3 & 4
                                                     \end{smallmatrix}\right)} k^{2}$
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
with matrix 3 x 2 and use of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
For linear transformation  $k^{3} \xrightarrow{\begin{psmallmatrix}
                                                               1 & 2 & 3\\
                                                               4 & 5 & 6
                                               \end{psmallmatrix}} k^{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your TABstacks for fontsize, column gap, and baselineskip.  Here are two examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
\setstacktabbedgap{.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptscriptstyle}
\setstacktabbedgap{.4ex}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}
For non-linear transformation  $k^{3} \xrightarrow{
  \parenMatrixstack{x & y^2\\2x & y}
} k^{2}$

\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
\setstacktabbedgap{.6ex}
\setstackgap{L}{10pt}
For non-linear transformation  $k^{3} \xrightarrow{
  \parenMatrixstack{x & y^2\\2x & y}
} k^{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is also this alternative code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\smat}[4]{\begin{psmallmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{psmallmatrix}}
\begin{document}
For linear transformation
\begin{tikzcd}
& k^3 \arrow[r, "\smat{1}{2}{3}{4}"] & k^2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```